# I'am able to build but not run my SwiftUI project on local device

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I am facing the problem that I can build my project but not running it on my device (iPhone 12 Pro Max).

The error:

```
Details

Unable to install "VRTwente"
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402620395
User Info: {
    DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2023-02-24 09:26:52 +0000";
    IDERunOperationFailingWorker = IDEInstalliPhoneLauncher;
}
--
A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found.
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402620395
User Info: {
    DVTRadarComponentKey = 487925;
    MobileDeviceErrorCode = "(0xE8008015)";
    "com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace" = (
    0   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x00000001104382bc DTDKCreateNSErrorFromAMDErrorCode + 300
    1   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000011046c3c0 __90-[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:]_block_invoke + 136
    2   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000105f1a0e0 DVTInvokeWithStrongOwnership + 76
    3   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000011046c144 -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:] + 1196
    4   IDEiOSSupportCore                   0x0000000110147c34 __118-[DVTiOSDevice(DVTiPhoneApplicationInstallation) processAppInstallSet:appUninstallSet:installOptions:completionBlock:]_block_invoke.147 + 2328
    5   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010602499c __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ + 16
    6   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000106025408 __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 152
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001a44949dc _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001a4496504 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001a449dbbc _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 672
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001a449e708 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 384
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001a44a934c _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 652
    12  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001a4619100 _pthread_wqthread + 288
    13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001a4617e20 start_wqthread + 8
);
}
--

Analytics Event: com.apple.dt.IDERunOperationWorkerFinished : {
    "device_model" = "iPhone13,4";
    "device_osBuild" = "16.3.1 (20D67)";
    "device_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphoneos";
    "launchSession_schemeCommand" = Run;
    "launchSession_state" = 1;
    "launchSession_targetArch" = arm64;
    "operation_duration_ms" = 2390;
    "operation_errorCode" = "-402620395";
    "operation_errorDomain" = "com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain";
    "operation_errorWorker" = IDEInstalliPhoneLauncher;
    "operation_name" = IDEiPhoneRunOperationWorkerGroup;
    "param_consoleMode" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToExtensions" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToXPC" = 1;
    "param_debugger_type" = 5;
    "param_destination_isProxy" = 0;
    "param_destination_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphoneos";
    "param_diag_MainThreadChecker_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableDuringAttach" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableForXPC" = 1;
    "param_diag_allowLocationSimulation" = 1;
    "param_diag_checker_tpc_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_gpu_frameCapture_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_shaderValidation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_validation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_memoryGraphOnResourceException" = 0;
    "param_diag_queueDebugging_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_runtimeProfile_generate" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_asan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_ubsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_showNonLocalizedStrings" = 0;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_enabled" = 1;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_insertDylibOnLaunch" = 1;
    "param_install_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_UID" = 2;
    "param_launcher_allowDeviceSensorReplayData" = 0;
    "param_launcher_kind" = 0;
    "param_launcher_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_substyle" = 0;
    "param_runnable_appExtensionHostRunMode" = 0;
    "param_runnable_productType" = "com.apple.product-type.application";
    "param_runnable_type" = 2;
    "param_testing_launchedForTesting" = 0;
    "param_testing_suppressSimulatorApp" = 0;
    "param_testing_usingCLI" = 0;
    "sdk_canonicalName" = "iphoneos16.2";
    "sdk_osVersion" = "16.2";
    "sdk_variant" = iphoneos;
}
--


System Information

macOS Version 13.1 (Build 22C65)
Xcode 14.2 (21534) (Build 14C18)
Timestamp: 2023-02-24T10:26:52+01:00
```

I've already searched for solutions but nothing works, already added device to developer account etc.
For example:

- Reinstall certificates
- Reconfigurate certificates
- Delete derived data & rebuild project
- Removed device & reconfigure device
- Simulator does work

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your phone for previous built apps? Reading your error it seems like your phone is blocking installation. You could try to your phone settings, and it should be inside VPN- and devicemanagement. Also this tutorial could help out https://codewithchris.com/deploy-your-app-on-an-iphone/

Another possibility is cleaning up your simulator cache with CMD + SHIFT + K. Hope this helps!

You can check if the provisioning profile is installed by connecting the device to your Mac:

1. Open the Devices and Simulators window from XCode.
2. Highlight your device and do a control + click, then go to Show Provisioning Profiles...
3. If your provisioning profile is not there you can manually add it by clicking on the +
4. Navigate to the provisioning profile and add it
5. Build your application again and it should install

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have tried this solution as well, unfortunately this solution is not working for me. I've noticed you come from the Netherlands, I do as well so maybe we can reach out?

Comment: Sure thing! You can look me up on github or linkedin!